# Didnt work click on radio. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

Trying to add a message, when somebody choose the radiobutton. But I got this message  with "0" only when page is load, not when I clicked on radiobutton. Can u tell me why?

```
var a3 = 0;

    if(document.getElementById('q3know').checked) {
        a3 = 40;


    }else if(document.getElementById('q3no').checked) {
        a3 = 0;
    }

    function clicker(){
        document.getElementById('q3know').click().alert(a3);
    };
```

Comment: This isn't a text message. Try using the word "you".

Comment: Didn't work in what way? What was the problem? Also, your alert won't return a value, so isn't a valid argument to `click()`. Try placing the alert after the call to `click()`, as a separate statement.

Comment: already edit my question. There is no message. 

But Im try your solution, and there still no alert(

Comment: Check your console, `.click().alert(a3)` is causing an error and stopping execution, as Adrian noted. You can't just chain methods like that.

Comment: To add to what @bfav is saying, you can chain like that in jQuery, but not in JavaScript. If you can switch to jQuery, it will certainly smooth out the rough edges of working with the DOM directly!

Comment: thanks, bfavaretto! Console is realy help. That's right desicion:
`document.getElementById('q3know').onclick = alert(a3);`

But for now I got another kind of trouble! That show me alert when my page is load, but not when radiobutton is clicked

Comment: (Btw, you need to ping someone using @bfavaretto, not just their name. Try typing the "at" symbol, then the first letter 'b', then auto-complete with `Tab`).

Comment: Ah, right: please edit your question and tag it as jQuery. That changes the answers you will get enormously.

Comment: It should be `document.getElementById('q3know').onclick = function(){ alert(a3); }` They way you did it, the alert was firing immediately, not being attached as an event handler. Event handlers must be function references.

Comment: so much thanks to you! It explains everything and it works. But its return "0". Why not "40" if I clicked on the q3know?

Comment: @halfer, thanks for your advices! Already did it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after all the comments above I think I understand what you're trying to do:

```
var a3 = 0;
document.getElementById('q3know').onclick = function() {
    if(document.getElementById('q3know').checked) {
        a3 = 40;
    } else if(document.getElementById('q3no').checked) {
        a3 = 0;
    }
    alert(a3);
}
```

Comment: yeah! Its thanks a lot for that! Now I see that browser checked radiobutton after click, but not before them. Its much more logical.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var a3 = 0;

if(document.getElementById('q3know').checked) {
    a3 = 40;


}else if(document.getElementById('q3no').checked) {
    a3 = 0;
}

function Clicker () {
    alert(a3);
}
```

On the HTML:

```
<input type="radio" onclick="Clicker();">
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery way:

```
$('#q3know').on('click', function() {
  var a3 = 0;
  if($(this).is(':checked')) {
    a3 = 40;
  } else if($('#q3no').is(':checked')) {
    a3 = 0;
  }
  alert(a3);
});
```